# Does it require to install Experience Optimization in presentation server in SDL8.5

Tags: smarttarget, experience-optimization

I have added QueryService Capability in Content Discovery. So do I need to install Experience Optimization in presentation server to fetch the ST promotion using Smart Target API?

Answer (score 2):

You will need the client API in your web application, so that it can talk to the service. That is available in the folder `Experience Optimization\Content Delivery\roles\api\rest` on the installation media and is referred to as "API (RESTful) Role" in the documentation.

There is [a large section](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-62BB9039-44CD-4EC3-8739-11097F0572D5) in the documentation explaining what needs to be installed for Experience Optimization to work, broken down into sub-sections. In this case, the relevant sub-section is "[Installing Experience Optimization on the presentation environment](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-6E58C583-A524-4299-8A3C-3E9017519BD6)".

Comment: Query service capability is configured on port 8094 in Content deployment server. This port is not enabled to be access outside of server box. So does it needs to opened for  presentation server which is different server.

Comment: Yes, the presentation server must be able to talk to the service(s) running on the back-end.

Comment: Port 8082 is accessible for discovery service from presentation server but port 8094  for query service is not accessible from presentation server. I was under the impression that while executing smarttarget query using smart target API IN DXA MODULE, it does not directly talk to query service instead talks to discovery service to fetch smart target promotion from query server. Please let me know whether the understanding correct.

Comment: It talks to the Discovery service to find out where the Query service lives (and to do authentication) -- but to actually get the Promotions it talks to the Query service. Same goes for every other service; the Discovery service isn't a proxy.

Comment: @Somen - Please don't forget to mark the answer if your query is answered

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no need to install anything in the Presentation server, just the Smart API call is sufficient enough